# running through all active windows with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: debian, gnome3

I would like to write a script (if there is not an already existing one) which allows me to go through all the active windows using a keyboard shortcut.
So for example I have active evolution, iceweasel and a xterm and I want that a combination like ctrl+something focuses the windows sequentially, (in any order, I do not mind). This is slightly different from alt+tab of course...

I am using Gnome 3 on Debian 8.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by 'active'? Not minimized? Unsure about Gnome 3, but MATE shifts minimized windows to the end of the alt-tab list; don't know if that's enough.

Comment: with "active" I mean all the applications which appear when I go in focus mode

Comment: Sounds like a Gnome 3 thing. You'd have to look into whatever scripting facilities that offers.